# Muliple instances in Jboss 6.3.0 EAP as serive in a single machine

Tags: java, jndi, jboss6.x

I am using Jboss 6.3.0 EAP in my project. I want to run multiple projects in my jboss server as service in one machine only.

I tried using "https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html-single/Installation_Guide/index.html". Here i am able to run one instance as service. But i am unable to run multiple services. To run with multiple instances i have taken two standlone folders and create one service2.bat(created newly by copying existing) in "jboss_home\modules\system\layers\base\native\sbin". And changed this to point to bin/standalone2.bat(created newly by copying existing) and in  standalone2.bat also i changed conf to point to newly created standalone folder.
Here, am i doing anything wrong. I am unable to run multiple instances.